# How does laravel/lumen dateformat 'U' actually works?

Tags: laravel, lumen

I'm not able get the timestamps with dateformat 'U' working in lumen.

**In migration:**

```
        $table->timestamps();
```

**In Model:**

```
protected $dateFormat = 'U';

protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'deleted_at'
];

public function getDateFormat()
{
    return 'U';
}
```

**Insert row from controller:**

```
    $model = new ApiKey;
    $model->random= rand();
    $model->name = $name;
    $model->scope = $scope;
    $model->save();
```

It does insert the row in the database but with **0000-00-00 00:00:00** values for created_at and updated_at columns.

Also, while retrieving a model via toArray or toJson it thrown exception:

[image]

I want lumen to autoupdate the timestamps and retrive timestamps as **unixtimestamp format** i.e. number of seconds from 1st Jan 1970.

Also, `$table->timestamps()` didn't create deleted_at column. What do I need to do get this column created via laravel.

Is there any other option than `$table->timestamp('deleted_at');`?

I've found a solution bay changing timestamps columns to int. But I want the things to be done in laravel way.

Comment: ... why are you using timestamp fields with a 'U' format??

Comment: This should help with the soft delete column. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#soft-deleting

Comment: @Devon, I want to show these fields in U format. In database It can still stay as datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unix timestamps are integers, not compatible with SQL datetime/timestamp fields.  If you want to use unix timestamps, use integer field types for storage.

The timestamps() method only creates created_at and updated_at, soft deletes are not enabled by default.  This method should not be used if you want integer storage.

---

If you only want to change the output format when serializing data, use casting:

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime:U',
];
```

Comment: I do not care much about the integer storage. I want to read it as integer. I mean that what `protected $dateFormat = 'U';` is supposed to do. right?

Comment: That changes how it's stored and serialized.   Read the docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Comment: @KetanYekale i updated my answer with casting as documented in the link I shared

Comment: Thank you Devon. Seems to make sense. I'll try this.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by the fact that Laravel/Lumen created the date/time columns as the type `timestamp` not `int` so you're trying to save wrong type of data in the field, causing the `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

This would also cause the carbon issue as you are trying to `createFromFormat` with the wrong format compared to the content.

You can use `$table->integer('deleted_at');` in your migration to create a `deleted_at` column.

TL;DR:

Manually create your date time columns with `$table->integer('updated_at')`.

Comment: You wouldn't want to use softDeletes() since that would create a timestamp field.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

trait sqlServerDateFormat
{

    public function fromDateTime($value)
    {
        return Carbon::parse(parent::fromDateTime($value))->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
    }

}
```

Comment: <?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

trait sqlServerDateFormat
{

    public function fromDateTime($value)
    {
        return Carbon::parse(parent::fromDateTime($value))->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
    }

}

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it